# Configuring xymon client in local mode

Tags: hobbitmon

I am trying to configure xymon (ex hobbit or bigbrother) in local mode. Basically the client would not send any data to the server. When using the --debug option the following information is obtained.

> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 Want msg 1, startpos 0, fillpos 0, endpos -1, usedbytes=0, bufleft=528383
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 Got 150930 bytes
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 /opt/xymon/client/bin/xymond_client: Got message 1 @@client#1|0|127.0.0.1|hostname|linux
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 startpos 150930, fillpos 150930, endpos -1
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 Opening file /opt/xymon/client/etc/localclient.cfg
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 Client report from host hostname
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 hostname: Duplicate client message at time 0, seq 1, lastseq 0
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 Want msg 2, startpos 150930, fillpos 150930, endpos -1, usedbytes=0, bufleft=377453
>
> 31017 2015-02-02 15:51:39 get_xymond_message: Returning NULL due to EOF

This bug seems to be the same than:
http://lists.xymon.com/archive/2012-February/033896.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution was given by the person hosting:
http://terabithia.org/rpms/xymon/
Many thanks to him. And I though I should report it here.

So it consisted in changing the following line in xymonclient.sh:

> echo "@@client#1|0|127.0.0.1|$MACHINEDOTS|$SERVEROSTYPE" >> $MSGTMPFILE

To:

> echo "@@client#1|1|127.0.0.1|$MACHINEDOTS|$SERVEROSTYPE" >> $MSGTMPFILE

And then data was sent to the server. Not sure what is going on here but that could help.